# What was the status of Abortion Rights in 1990's Islamic State of Afghanistan?

Tags: history, afghanistan, abortion

When the Taliban previously ruled Afghanistan in the 90s, did they have a policy regarding abortion rights for women? Was abortion permitted at all, and if so under what terms?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abortion_in_Saudi_Arabia should be a hint.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Wikipedia page about [the treatment of women by the Taliban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treatment_of_women_by_the_Taliban):

> Women in Afghanistan were forced to wear the burqa at all times in public, because, according to one Taliban spokesman, "the face of a woman is a source of corruption" for men not related to them. In a systematic segregation sometimes referred to as gender apartheid, women were not allowed to work, they were not allowed to be educated after the age of eight, and until then were permitted only to study the Qur'an.
>
> Women seeking an education were forced to attend underground schools, where they and their teachers risked execution if caught. They were not allowed to be treated by male doctors unless accompanied by a male chaperone, which led to illnesses remaining untreated. They faced public flogging and execution for violations of the Taliban's laws. The Taliban allowed and in some cases encouraged marriage for girls under the age of 16. Amnesty International reported that 80% of Afghan marriages were forced.

The page doesn't mention anything about abortion rights, but it would be absurd to imagine that abortion was permitted when women are not even allowed to access basic education or to work, and are routinely married by force.

Comment: What about abortion rights for men?  Could a man decide that his wife was going to get an abortion?

Comment: @Mark I don't have a precise answer, but one can assume that, if there was any law about abortion, it was based on [religious grounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_and_abortion). But it's important to realize that Afghanistan didn't (and still doesn't) have a fully functioning and unified government in the same sense as western democracies, it probably didn't have a clear corpus of laws, existing laws were certainly not known to all the citizens (the literacy rate was 31% in 2011) and the enforcement of the laws was very likely variable. We're talking about a country where the ...

Comment: ... concept of legality barely makes sense given the importance of tribal rule and corruption, so I doubt that a quite advanced topic like abortion had a clearly defined legal status. Sadly when most people don't have access to the most basic healthcare, access to abortion is not a top priority.

Comment: Afghanistan has had Islamic law as its highest legal authority from the 1990s to the present. But, this is rather vague. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_and_abortion There is not a consensus among Islamic countries attempting to apply Islamic law. The Taliban are associated with Deobandi Islam. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deobandi This is an offshoot of a school of Islam that permits abortions up to four months, but would probably color that with the notion that a male guardian should make all decisions for a woman.